# How to perform media queries if either statements are correct?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile, mobile

I'm looking to find out how to perform css based on whether either one of two statements is true. For example:

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape)
OR
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait){

}
```

I'm making a multi-platform website and have finished the mobile version, however I want iPads to have the laptop/desktop version, all was working good with this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 0px){Mobile Version CSS}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 500px){Other Version CSS}
```

But then I noticed after changing a mobile to landscape, it would switch back to the desktop mode, due to the width of the media query being less than the screens landscape width. What's the best set of media queries, that I can perform in two different queries, just for mobile and other platform, that take in account a phone being landscape or portrait? I don't want to have to repeat my CSS code through multiple media queries because of phones going landscape and such. I just want the mobile version to be active whether a mobile is landscape or portrait.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's nothing a quick google search couldn't have revealed to you: (first try) https://css-tricks.com/logic-in-media-queries/

media-query logic:

- And: `and`
- Or: `,`
- Not: `not`

In your case, your **CSS** would look like:

```
@media
  only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape),
  only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* your css here */
}
```

*Just some reminders:*

1. Your media-query do not serve the situations "portrait and device-width < 768px" and "device-width > 1024px". You need to address those cases too somehow.
2. While an iPad (in ladnscape) has a screen-width of 1024px, you would present your websites desktop view to any other phones/tablets having a width of at least 768px, too. I don't think that's a good idea. But I don't know what your website looks like, so I assume you know what you're doing.
3. BTW: Wouldn't a grid-system like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) do a lot for you?